# REST API DELETE LIST ITEM - USE THIS CODE

Tags: sharepoint, office365api

Delete Items:

This Code will help to delete the item in list using REST API for SharePoint.

`var SiteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items('" + courtids + "')";`

```
        $.ajax({
              url: SiteUrl 
                         method: 'DELETE',
                         headers: {
                             'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                         },


            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Delete success");

            },
            error: function (data) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please clean up this formatting and actually ask a question?

Answer (score 2):

To delete item using REST API, the following example code for your reference.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var listName="listName";
    var itemId=1;
    $("#deleteItem").click(function(){
        deleteItem(listName,itemId);
    });
});
function deleteItem(listName,itemId){
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items(" + itemId + ")";
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"  
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Delete success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input id="deleteItem" type="button" value="Delete Item"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to reinvent the wheel. You should use the pnpjs: a microsoft library which uses the rest api to perform actions on sharepoint.

[PNPJS](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items)